# "I'll be sure to do something" vs "I'll for sure do something"

Tags: idioms, semantics, north-american-english

I'm not a native speaker but work in an English-speaking international environment. One American guy wrote me:

> I'll be sure to let you know

We at our company usually say:

> I'll for sure let you know

Are both ways correct and are there any semantic distinctions between them?
If both are acceptable, which expression is more common in America?

Comment: Interposing a multi-word adverbial phrase in between the two components of a compound verb form like *I **will let** you know* isn't particularly idiomatic for native speakers, so I assume your company isn't primarily Anglophonic. But it's fine with single-word adverbs, as in *I'll **definitely** let you know*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *I will be sure to let you know* sounds like the Queen's English to me - perfectly idiomatic in formal register. *I'll for sure let you know* does sound American. It would be unusual to hear it said that way by someone born and bred in the UK.

Comment: @WS2: It's not easy to use online resources to home in on *spoken* usages, but my feeling is native speaker Americans also tend to avoid splitting compound verbs with multi-word adverbs. To me, OP's cited usage sounds more like "non-native speaker" than "typical American".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are perfectly good American English.  The "for sure" version is slightly more informal.  That qualifier "for sure" reminds some of us of the popular 1983 film *Valley Girl* and valspeak. "Valspeak is a common name for an American sociolect, originally of Southern Californians, in particular valley girls." ([see Language Dossier](http://language-dossier.webs.com/americanslangvalspeak.htm)).

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that the "for sure" (typically pronounced *fer sher*) version is ***way*** more informal.

Comment: In doing research for this answer, I ran across the following interview with Frank Zappa in which Moon Unit does her depiction of valspeak.  She's good.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TZk1gYj2xo